# Two remote repositories out of sync (non-fast-forwards error)

Tags: git, github

I have two remote repositories in Bitbucket and Github that have been set up to sync `master` branch from Bitbucket to Github (one-way sync) by running this shell script regularly:

```
git clone --mirror https://$bitbucket_url/repo.git $REPO
cd $REPO
git remote add --mirror=fetch github https://$GIT_TOKEN@$github_url/repo.git
git fetch origin
git push --tags github master
```

The synchronisation has been doing its job well but it started to get rejected recently with the following error (real git token and github url have been masked below):

> ! [rejected]          master -> master (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://$GIT_TOKEN_MASKED@$github_url/repo.git'
> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
> hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Based on the error message, I understand that there are commits on Github that Bitbucket doesn't have? So I need to do a `git pull` from github before `git push`? I did attempt that but it was complaining that I can't do `git pull` because there is no working tree. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: It isn't clear how the github copy of the repo got out of sync like this. But since this is entirely a one-way operation where you're just trying to copy the repo from bitbucket to github, I would suggest simply _deleting_ the github repo, making a new empty repo (with the same name if you like), and then run your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Git reference material (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) using `--mirror` when cloning will create a bare repository, intended to be used to push between two remotes.  A bare repository has no working tree, no checked out branch or commit and therefore nothing to `pull` into.  Note, that a `pull` entails a `fetch` and a `merge`, but in this case there is nothing to `merge` into.

From the Git reference material:

> `--mirror`
>
> Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies `--bare`. Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only maps local branches of the source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a `git remote update` in the target repository.

After line 4 of your code, your local repository will contain all branches and tags from the Bitbucket repository, but the repository will have no working copy and no commit or branch will be checked out.

On line 5 (`git push --tags github master`) your `push` is failing because the head commit of the `master` branch on the Github server is not a parent to the `master` branch that you are attempting to `push` to it (i.e. non-fast-forward) and the server is trying to prevent you from undoing something that is already there.  This probably means that someone pushed a commit to the `master` branch on the Github server, which was never pushed to the Bitbucket server.

If you were to attempt to `pull` from the Github server at this point, there would be nothing to `pull` into, since you are working from a bare repo.

To synchronize the two, you will need to use the following steps:

1. `git clone` the Bitbucket server somewhere, without mirroring.
2. Checkout the `master` branch.
3. Add the Github server as a remote using `remote add` without mirroring.
4. `git pull` the `master` branch on the Github server into your local `master` branch, which should already be checked out.
5. If there are merge conflicts, you will need to resolve them and complete the `merge`.
6. `git push` the local `master` branch to each remote so that you finish with both remotes in synch.

To avoid having this problem in the future, you may want to add some safegaurds to your Github server to prevent users from pushing to the `master` branch there since it is intended to be updated using your script.

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what I think happened on Github repo although I'm not able to find any commit from Github that doesn't exist on Bitbucket. I'm pretty sure your proposed solution will work once I merge and resolve the conflicts. However I eventually went with renaming the Github repo and start a new Github repo with the same name. It's syncing OK with the new repo but I still cannot identify the root cause.